# Dynamic Data Display WPF Binding in MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, dynamic-data-display

So, I'd like to bind the data source of a **LineGraph** to a **CompositeDataSource** in a wpf app with MVVM pattern. Here is what I've done so far:

The relevant line in the XAML:

```
<d3:LineGraph DataSource="{Binding signal}" Stroke="Blue"/>
```

signal is my **CompositeDataSource** object.

Relevant part of my ViewModel:

```
private void LoadSignalExecuted()
    {
        OnLoadSignal();

        plotter.CreateGraph(dataFile);
        signal = plotter.ECGData;

        OnPropertyChanged("signal");
    }
```

OnLoadSignal() does nothing important in this case. **plotter** is a class in my Model namespace. The CreateGraph(dataFile) does nothing else but populates a

```
public List<Points> Values { get; private set; }
```

object. It's populated correctly, I checked. My Points class is the following:

```
class Points
{

    public Double X { get; set; }
    public Double Y { get; set; }

    public Points(Double xData, Double yData)
    {
        X = xData;
        Y = yData;
    }

}
```

plotter.ECGData looks like this:

```
public CompositeDataSource ECGData
    {
        get
        {

                var xData = new EnumerableDataSource<double>(Values.Select(v => v.X));
                xData.SetXMapping(x => x);
                var yData = new EnumerableDataSource<double>(Values.Select(v => v.Y));
                yData.SetYMapping(y => y);
                _data = xData.Join(yData);

                return _data;
        }
    }
```

Where _data is a **CompositeDataSource** of course.

I figured this would work but the LineGraph doesn't appear upon OnPropertyChanged("signal"), which is implemented correctly I'm positive about that. 
VS Output Box says:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'signal' property not found on 'object' ''ECGViewModel' (HashCode=41182536)'. BindingExpression:Path=signal; DataItem='ECGViewModel' (HashCode=41182536); target element is 'LineGraph' (Name=''); target property is 'DataSource' (type 'IPointDataSource')
```

Can someone point out the mistake here? Thanks!

Comment: What does the 'signal' property look like?

Comment: Have you taken a look to the VS Output box ?

Comment: @ChrisMantle "signal" is a CompositeDataSource. It's never used except for when it's assigned a value, in this case plotter.ECGData which is also CompositeDataSource. I needed this not to ruin the mvvm pattern. Btw I followed a tutorial and in the comments they said this worked for them that's why I'm puzzled.

Comment: @HichemCSharp I've added the info to the question.

Comment: And the `signal` property definitely exists on `ECGViewModel`? And it's definitely a property, not just a variable? And it has a getter as well as a setter?

Comment: @ChrisMantle I've done many data bindings before, I used the same method every time and this is the first time it's not working. I declared signal like this: `public CompositeDataSource signal { get; private set; }` and it exists on ECGViewModel.

Comment: Well, that is strange. More silly questions, then. Is `ECGViewModel` in a different project? Have you tried a full rebuild? Perhaps you have an old version of `ECGViewModel` around that actually doesn't have the `signal` property on it. Also, can you turn up your data binding information in the Output Window and see if there's any more detail? (Tools menu –> Options –> Debugging –> Output Window –> WPF Trace Settings –> Data Binding, set to something like Verbose or All)

Comment: @ChrisMantle I don't want to curse but HOLY CR*P! You were right: after deleting the obj folder everything is ok. It's one project though but this comment led me to find a solution. If you post this I'll mark it as an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `ECGViewModel` in a different project? Have you tried a full rebuild? Perhaps you have an old version of `ECGViewModel` around that actually doesn't have the signal property on it.

Comment: Same project, but different obj folder. Thank you!